# Cancelling upload request before destroying object makes mobx-state-tree throw Cannot modify [dead] errors

Tags: react-native, axios, mobx-state-tree

I have a React Native app where I want to upload some files using Axios.

I've made a mobx-state-tree store for file uploads, and each file has its own `CancelTokenSource`, which is sent to the Axios network call.

When an upload is in progress, I try to cancel the upload, and then destroy the item.

The simplest way is like I show below, by destroying the item in the store, and then have an `beforeDestroy()` hook that cancels the upload. But that approach makes mobx-state-tree show the error in the screenshot.

I've also tried calling the `file.cancelTokenSource.cancel()` explicitly before destroying the item. Same error. I suspect that the operation is not fully cancelled when the `cancel()` returns, but since it's not an async function, I cannot `await` its completion.

When I just call the `cancel()` without destroying, it cancels just fine, so I'm pretty sure  that it's a timing issue, where the `destroy(file)` is called too soon, before `cancel()` has cleaned up after itself.

What to do here?

[image]

file-upload-store.ts

```
import { destroy, flow, Instance, types } from 'mobx-state-tree'

import { FileUpload, IFileUpload } from '../entities/file-upload/file-upload'
import { getApi } from '../../store-environment'

/**
 * Store for handling the FileUpload
 */
export const FileUploadStore = types
  .model('FileUploadStore')
  .props({
    files: types.array(FileUpload),
  })
  .actions((self) => {
    const api = getApi(self)

    const add = (uri: string, name: string, type: string, size: number) => {
      const file = FileUpload.create({
        uri,
        name,
        type,
        size,
      })
      self.files.push(file)
      upload(file)
    }

    const remove = (file: IFileUpload) => {
      destroy(file)
    }

    const cancel = (file: IFileUpload) => {
      // also tried this - with no luck
      // file.cancelTokenSource.cancel()
      destroy(file)
    }

    const upload = flow(function* (file: IFileUpload) {
      file.status = 'pending'
      file.uploadedBytes = 0
      const { uri, name, type } = file

      try {
        const id = yield api.uploadFile(uri, name, type, file.setProgress, file.cancelTokenSource.token)
        file.status = 'completed'
        file.fileUploadId = id
      } catch (error) {
        file.status = 'failed'
        file.error = error.message
      }
    })

    return {
      afterCreate() {
        // Avoid persistance
        self.files.clear()
      },
      remove,
      cancel,
      retry: upload,
      add,
    }
  })

export type IFileUploadStore = Instance<typeof FileUploadStore>
```

file-upload.ts

```
import { Instance, SnapshotIn, types } from 'mobx-state-tree'
import { CancelToken } from 'apisauce'

/**
 * FileUpload contains the particular data of a file, and some flags describing its status.
 */
export const FileUpload = types
  .model('FileUpload')
  .props({
    name: types.string,
    type: types.string,
    uri: types.string,
    size: types.number,
    // set if an arror occours
    error: types.maybe(types.string),
    status: types.optional(types.enumeration(['pending', 'completed', 'failed']), 'pending'),
    // updated by progressCallback
    uploadedBytes: types.optional(types.number, 0),
    // assigned when response from backend is received
    fileUploadId: types.maybe(types.string),
  })
  .volatile(() => ({
    cancelTokenSource: CancelToken.source(),
  }))
  .actions((self) => ({
    setProgress(event: ProgressEvent) {
      self.uploadedBytes = event.loaded
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
      self.cancelTokenSource?.cancel()
    },
  }))

export interface IFileUpload extends Instance<typeof FileUpload> {}
// SnapshotIn, used for creating input to store: {Model}.create({})
export interface IFileUploadSnapshotIn extends SnapshotIn<typeof FileUpload> {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are destroying the `FileUpload` node and cancelling the `axios` request nicely, but cancelling the request will throw an error, so you need to make sure that your `FileUpload` node is still alive before you try to update it in the `catch`.

```js
import { destroy, flow, Instance, types, isAlive } from 'mobx-state-tree'

// ...

const upload = flow(function* (file: IFileUpload) {
  const { uri, name, type } = file

  file.status = "pending"
  file.uploadedBytes = 0

  try {
    const id = yield api.uploadFile(
      uri,
      name,
      type,
      file.setProgress,
      file.cancelTokenSource.token
    )

    file.status = "completed"
    file.fileUploadId = id
  } catch (error) {
    if (isAlive(file)) {
      file.status = "failed"
      file.error = error.message
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I did not think about the exception thrown by axios when cancelling, as something that could make it try to set a failed status.